# Can't log in to NETGEAR wnr612v3

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have a NETGEAR wnr612v3. It was working fine until I did a reset recently. Now when I try to log in it does not accept its default username and password. To more surprise when I am trying to open any search site( Google, Yahoo, Bing etc ), it asks for username and password as if I'm trying to log in.
How do I fix this ?

**EDIT**
Adding Screenshots:
1. This is what you get when you try to go to Google/Bing/Yahoo etc

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5aZVQjlGn3uMzhZV09xSy05TDQ/view?usp=drivesdk

2. When you enter username : admin and password : password, this page shows

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5aZVQjlGn3uQzBLcXMtRXp2OEE/view?usp=drivesdk

3. You can open facebook
4. But when you try to open a link from facebook( here sciencealert ) you get a screen like point 2.

Comment: "Reset" is ambiguous. Could you [edit] to be more specific? What *exactly* did you do? Also, can you include a screenshot of what you see when you are being asked for the username and password? You can upload the image anywhere and include the URL in your question; assuming that it is legitimate, someone will edit the image into the question.

Comment: Reset means pushing the button behind router that you have to push for about 20-30 sec.

Comment: Have you tried to reset your router again?

Comment: Yes 2 times since then

Comment: How do you connect to the internet? Do you have an additional ADSL/VDSL modem? Do you have to configure the Netgear to do anything with your ISP? Dial a connection?

Comment: Your screenshots are the same :/

Comment: Have you opened screenshots because I'm getting different ?

Answer (score 1):

Something went wrong during the standard reset procedure. You can try to connect to your router by typing its IP in your browser's address bar. The IP of the router is your default gateway in your network connection. You can find it in your network connection details.

If this fails you can try and do the so-called 30/30/30 reset. This will erase all data in the NVRAM of the router and it should go back to factory default settings. This should be done if you did not try to change your stock firmware with another. If that's the case - it's a whole different story. Anyway here is the 30/30/30 reset procedure:

1. With the router powered on, hold the reset button in for 30 seconds.
2. Continue to hold the reset button in and unplug the router, holding it in for another 30 seconds.
3. Plug the router back in, with the reset button still held, and continue to hold it in for another 30 seconds.